# Download File from linux server via website

Tags: html, linux, web

So I have a Linux server and I want to download a file from "/home/file.txt"

I want to provide a download link for this file on my website.

Also I cannot move the file AT ALL.

How would I go about doing this...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow indexing the files on your web server - here are instructions for apache:http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/enabling-apache-file-directory-indexing/

Then all you have to do is add the anchor tag to your html:

```
 <a href="http://home/file.txt" target="_blank">file.txt</a>
```

I have done this many times using server side scripting but that might be more than you need and this should work for you just as it is. Also if you cannot move the file and don't want to allow indexing the home directory you might want to create a symbolic link to it instead like this:http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-make-or-create-symbolic-link-in-unix-or-linux/

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script that will serve the file from your home directory through your website.

Here is a PHP example that you can put on your site somewhere, like yoursite.com/downloadfile.php.

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/plain'); // tell browser it is a text file

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.txt"'); // forces download prompt

readfile('/home/file.txt'); // read and output the contents of the file to browser
```

For this you will need to have a working PHP install on the web server and the http server will need the read access to that file.

You can achieve the same using many other languages, like Perl, or Bash.